# ListView formatting when reading from text file

Tags: c#, listview

I'm trying to read data from a text file and populate that data in a listview. However, when I read the data in and then add it to the listview, it is trying to put everything on the same line just in different columns. I would like it to read each line of the txt file and put each line in its own row in the listview. Can anyone help  me out with this? Not much experience using listviews, or reading from text files for that matter. 
Thanks for any help.

```
       string path = @"..\..\blah.txt";
       StreamReader textIn = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
       while (textIn.Peek() != -1)
       {
           string str = textIn.ReadLine();
           listviewOptions.Items.Add(str);
       }
       textIn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to read and populate your listview in one go:

```
listviewOptions.Items.AddRange(File.ReadLines(@"..\..\blah.txt").ToArray());
```

It uses `File.ReadLines` method to read lines from your file and `List.Items.AddRange` to add them all.